# How to update array of values in hiberbate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I am trying to update to array of values using Hibernate. The rows are updated when I am doing it but every time I am getting row affected values as 1. Why?

```
public int promoteStudentsToNextClass(String[] studentsRefrenceIDS,String promotedClassValue) { 
        int r = 0;
        Session session = null;
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            String hql = "update StudentDTO set studentClassName=? where studentReferenceID=?";
            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
            for (int i = 0; i < studentsRefrenceIDS.length; i++) {          
                query.setParameter(0, promotedClassValue);
                query.setParameter(1, studentsRefrenceIDS[i]);  
                 r=query.executeUpdate();               
                    System.out.println("row updated "+r);
            }       


            tx.commit();
        return r;
        } catch (HibernateException he) {
            he.printStackTrace();
            tx.rollback();
        }
        return r;
    }
```

This is not bulk even though not giving row affected value correctly

```
public boolean updateStudentsAttendance(StudentAttendanceDTO attendanceDTO) {
        Date date =new Date();
        attendanceDTO.setModifiedBy("Admin");
        attendanceDTO.setModifiedOn(date);
        Session session = null;
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            String hql = "update StudentAttendanceDTO set attendanceStatus=?,reasonForAbsent=?,modifiedBy=?,modifiedOn=? where className=? and studentReferenceID=?  ";
            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
            query.setParameter(0, attendanceDTO.getAttendanceStatus());
            query.setParameter(1, attendanceDTO.getReasonForAbsent());
            query.setParameter(2, attendanceDTO.getModifiedBy());
            query.setParameter(3, attendanceDTO.getModifiedOn());
            query.setParameter(4, attendanceDTO.getClassName());
            query.setParameter(5, attendanceDTO.getStudentReferenceID());

            int r=query.executeUpdate();            
            System.out.println("row updated "+r);           
            tx.commit();
            if(r==1)
            {
                return true;
            }

        } catch (HibernateException he) {
            he.printStackTrace();
            tx.rollback();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you perform a bulk update, which is by using the executeUpdate() method, you are bypassing the in-memory PersistenceContext (jpa terminology) and going straight to the database and executing whatever the query is.

This is not the case for operations like save(), saveOrUpdate(), or simply using find() to get the entity and modifying it. Those manipulate the PersistenceContext without going directly to the database. That is done automatically when transaction method processing is finishied and whatever changes were made they are flushed all at once.

If you want to have you database update only once in the given transaction then try doing this:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
 session = sessionFactory.openSession();
 tx = session.beginTransaction();
 for (int i = 0; i < studentsRefrenceIDS.length; i++) { 
    StudentDTO student = session.find(StudentDTO.class, studentsRefrenceIDS[i]);
    student.setStudentClassName(promotedClassValue);
 }

tx.commit();
```

Comment: see this is not bulk update even though not giving row affected values correctly

Comment: see the question again

Comment: when you use the executeUpdate().. its called 'batch / bulk update' and it doest matter whether you are trying to affect one or many rows in the query.